# How to setup the trigger build when pushing to github repo in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins 2.89.2 and my project has `Jenkinsfile` which defines all build pipeline and steps. I have searched online for triggering build when push to github repo and all of them mentioned an options `Build when a change was pushed to Github` in jenkins configuration page. But in my jenkins configuration page I couldn't find this options. Below is an screenshot. It only has one options `Periodically if not otherwise run`.  I have installed github related plugins but still I couldn't find that option. Is there any other configuration I can change?

[image]

Below is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    tools { 
        maven 'maven-3.5.2' 
        jdk 'jdk9' 
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Checkout SCM') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checkout from Git...'
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building '

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I think I find the solution. The trigger option can be defined in `jenkinsfile` as below:

```
pipelineTriggers([
      [$class: "GitHubPushTrigger"]
    ])
```

Comment: This does not seem like a good syntax for the Declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to create a HOOK from jenkins to gitHub, which is located under the Build Triggers option

[image]

This option should be available to you since you have the Git Plugin installed.

P.S. the solution you have mentioned will work only for Declarative Pipeline  and will not work if you plan to switch to scripted pipeline